# Get matching object type from HashMap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

First of all I'd like to say I'm fairly new into programming.
I store a few "extends" of superclass in the same HashMap.
(for example XY and XZ extends X - I store both X's, XY's and XZ's in the same HashMap).
I decided to do this for convenience - usually every time I do something, I need all of the classes that extends "X" - in this example "XY" and "XZ". Also There is no problem when I want to check whether single value is instance of specified type of object - I simply use "instanceof" formula. Let's say that I want to check if object of key "key" is instance of "XY":

```
X objectoftypeX = hashmap.get(key)
if(objectoftypeX instanceof XY){
    //do stuff
}
```

But here my question comes: how to iterate only through, for instance, XY's in this HashMap?
Is this possible without checking every single object individually?
Does it make sense to do this way?
Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maps are fairly simple structures that optimize one form of access (a lookup by key).  If you want to be able to quickly find items of a specific type, then you need to use a different structure.

For example, you could choose to make multiple maps, or making a nested map:

```
// Nested map, with the top level map indexing by Type (can be a String)
// and the maps inside it indexing by a String key.
Map<Type, Map<String, Object>> map = ...;
```

If you don't mind the overhead of checking every entry individually, you can easily get all the elements you want with a stream:

```
List<XY> list = hashmap.values().stream()
    .filter(v -> v instanceof XY)  // check type
    .map(v -> (XY) v)   // do cast
    .collect(Collectors.toList());  // collect to list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hashmap.entrySet().filter(item -> item.value() instanceOf X).forEach(item -> ...);
```

It is the same, but shoter

Comment: I don't think the keys are of type X, XY, XZ :)

Comment: Thanks) just mistype, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Object[] keySetArray = mMap.keySet().toArray();
for( int x = 0; x < keySetArray.length; x++ )
{
        final Object whatStored = mMap.get( keySetArray[x] );
        System.out.println("key[" + keySetArray[x] + "]: "+ whatStored );
    // Make sure this check happens as it is, if you stored XY and XZ that extended X  
         if( whatStored instanceof of XY || whatStored instanceof XZ )
         {
             if( whatStored instanceof XY )
             {
                  // Go here for instance X and XY
             }
             else if( whatStored instanceof XZ )
             {
                 // Go here for instance X and XZ
             }
         }
}
```

Hope this is Close??

Comment: I think it is close, but a bit more convoluted than needed.

Answer (score 0):

With standard hashmap its not possible to do this effectively (without going through everything). Purpose of hashmap is to provide fast access to elements, with only small memory overhead. Consider you have an array on integer size and a hashcode function which returns integer for each stored object. Then you will be able to find the element by applying index = hashcode(key), which is basically 1 operation to find anything. But you have a terrible memory overhead (array size is equal to all integers).

Other options would be to have a list and go through all the elements. Here you would have no memory overhead, but the search complexity would be O(n) - you would need to go through everything to be sure that the element is not in the array (or find it sooner).

Hashmap is in the middle. You allocate array of size lets say 100. Then you calculate hashcode function for the key and the result is 105. So you place the object on index {hashcode_result} modulo array_size. In our case 105 % 100 == 5.

The interesting stuff depends on implementation, what you will do, if you have a collision, which as a key2 with the same positon. For example if the hashcode value is 205, 305... (modulo will be 5 for all these hashcodes).
One possibility would be to add these additional elements to next available index 6, 7...
In java (or at least as far as I remember) the buckets are implemented as linked lists, so you will have

```
0 => []
1 => []
2 => []
3 => []
4 => []
5 => [k=105, k=205, k=305...]
```

The only way how to use hashmap for your use case would be to implement a hashcode function, which always generates the same hash for the same class. But this will degenerate the hashmap to n lists, where n is number of subclasses. And the lookup will terribly suffer (you will have to do M/n operations to lookup the value, where M is number of elements and n is the number of distinct classes), while correctly implemented hashmap (uniform distribution of hashcode values) guarantees that the number of lookups will be effectively equal to 1.

---

Long story short - because of the structure of hashmap, you can't do any type of data-dependent loopkup effectively (you wil kill the performance to searching through lists).
If you want to have this type of lookup, the answer of **john16384** is a really good one.